# How to use conditional statement or contains method in a text file?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, contains

I have a java program that can read multiple files and replace values accordingly. However, I am struggling to apply a condition to it and apply the changes only when a certain condition is met. For example, if the file contains this specific character ':20:' then apply the changes otherwise leave the text file as it is.
The problem here is, since I don't have fields to look for to apply the condition accordingly I don't know how these can be applied to such a text file which contains just data like : (12345555555) 233344 100 :20:aaa.

I also looked at using the contains() method to look into the file to find the value I want then apply the changes but couldn't make it work.

```
public class TextFm 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File folder = new File("C:\\tmp");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for(File file : listOfFiles) 
        {
            replaceText(file);
        }
    }

    public static void replaceText(File file) 
    {

        try 
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line = "", oldtext = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {

                oldtext = oldtext + line + System.lineSeparator();
            }
            reader.close();


            String replacedtext = oldtext.replaceAll("100", "200");


            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write(replacedtext);

            writer.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException ioe) 

        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `contains()` method will work fine in this case. You can do that like this:

```
String line = "", oldtext = "";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{

   oldtext = oldtext + line + System.lineSeparator();
}
reader.close();

if(oldtext.contains(":20:")) {
    String replacedtext = oldtext.replaceAll("100", "200");

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    writer.write(replacedtext);

    writer.close();

    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void replaceText(File file) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Charset charset = Charsets.defaulCharset();
            String oldText = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()),
                                        charset);

            if (!oldText.contains(":20")) {
                return;
            }
            if (!oldText.matches("(?s).*you (idiot|unspeakable).*")) {
                return;
            }
            String replacedtext = oldtext.replace("100", "200");
            replacedtext = replacedtext .replaceAll("\\d", "X"); // Digit X-ed out

            if (!replacedText.equals(oldText)) {
                Files.write(file.toPath(), replacedText.getBytes(charset));
            }
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (IOException ioe) 
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

For speed one should not collect the file contents with a String and +. Better use a `StringBuilder`, or the very nice `Files` class.

Finding text goes either by contains or by a regular expression match.
Replacement can be done by either too.

The `replace`, `replaceFirst` and `replaceAll` methods return the original string when nothing could be replaced.

Regex `(?s)` lets `.` (=any char) also match line breaks.

Comment: Many Thanks for this valuable information, However I used the contains method which wokrd just fine for me. Also, I would use StringBuilder in the future instead but not in this case.